# What is the mount option space_cache=v2?

Tags: mount, btrfs

[*"Debian 12 Bookworm Minimal Install w/BTRFS
"* by JustAGuy Linux at 8:28](https://youtu.be/MoWApyUb5w8?t=556) he sets an option for ssd,

```
mount -o ... space_cache=v2 ...
```

What is the option `space_cache=v2`? When should it be used, and when should it not be used? I don't see it documented in `man mount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see [`spache_cache` documented here](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-man5.html), but one thing that's important to note is that **it's the default since version 4.5**. Debian 12 ships kernel version 6.1. So it's just verbosely stating the defaults.

> **`space_cache`, `space_cache=<version>`, `nospace_cache`**
> (nospace_cache since: 3.2, space_cache=v1 and space_cache=v2 since 4.5, default: space_cache=v2)
>
> Options to control the free space cache. The free space cache greatly improves performance when reading block group free space into memory. However, managing the space cache consumes some resources, including a small amount of disk space.
>
> There are two implementations of the free space cache. The original one, referred to as v1, used to be a safe default but has been superseded by v2. The v1 space cache can be disabled at mount time with nospace_cache without clearing.
>
> On very large filesystems (many terabytes) and certain workloads, the performance of the v1 space cache may degrade drastically. The v2 implementation, which adds a new b-tree called the free space tree, addresses this issue. Once enabled, the v2 space cache will always be used and cannot be disabled unless it is cleared. Use clear_cache,space_cache=v1 or clear_cache,nospace_cache to do so. If v2 is enabled, and v1 space cache will be cleared (at the first mount) and kernels without v2 support will only be able to mount the filesystem in read-only mode. On an unmounted filesystem the caches (both versions) can be cleared by “btrfs check --clear-space-cache”.
>
> The btrfs-check(8) and :doc:`mkfs.btrfs commands have full v2 free space cache support since v4.19.
>
> If a version is not explicitly specified, the default implementation will be chosen, which is v2.