# Does Debian ship the documentation for btrfs?

Tags: debian, btrfs, man, documentation

While researching the answer for [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/752742/3285), I noticed there is a documentation page for [`man 5 btrfs`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-man5.html) that I see online. But I don't see that on Debian 12. Did this get shipped at all? How can I download this so I don't have to use the web interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on Debian is currently provided by `btrfs-progs`, which you can find like this,

```
apt-file search btrfs | grep -i man
```

Interestingly `apt info btrfs-progs` does not explicitly say it contains the man page for btrfs, and it's not in the title,

```
btrfs-progs - Checksumming Copy on Write Filesystem utilities
```

Comment: `btrfs-progs` provides the userspace tools for btrfs. I find it expectable that it includes the man pages for those tools. For the more general `man 5 btrfs`: since btrfs is part of the kernel who should provide the man page. It's the same for ext4 where `man 5 ext4` is provided by `e2fsprogs`.

Comment: @PaulPazderski but without `btrfs-progs` you can still `mount` btrfs volumes, right? It's supported by the kernel? (haven't actually tried this is just my first day to examine btrfs I'll play with it later tonight).

Comment: Yes. It is less confusing with ext-fs because Debian declares `e2fsprogs` as "required" so it is always there. `btrfs-progs` is in contrast "optional". A bit uncommon (imo) that you can have a system to mount btrfs without the tools to further manage it. But as you said, you can still mount it since it is part of the kernel.

Comment: @PaulPazderski Yeah, that's the confusing thing. Not having the tooling to manage it is understandable but imho it's not a good idea to have the support to mount it provided by the kernel and not the documentation to understand the options. I wish that one man page was backported. When I type in `man mount`, I can find "Mount options for fat" but not "Mount options for btrfs", even though both are equally supported by the kernel and have their tooling supported by external packages.